# ShellContent tag in .net maui not working

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-maui

trying to make a flyout menu in .net maui, from what i found out i have to use App.xaml for it, it does not seem to be working, here is the code in App.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NSM_Maui"
         x:Class="NSM_Maui.App">

<Application.MainPage>
    <Shell FlyoutBehavior="Flyout" FlyoutHeaderBehavior="Fixed" FlyoutVerticalScrollMode="Auto">
        <FlyoutItem Title="Home" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
        </FlyoutItem>
    </Shell>
</Application.MainPage>
```

it work fine up to the  but the  does not seem to be working, the Datatemplate string is a ContentPage xaml file that i made its called "HomePage" i was also following this video[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQfH1.png) https://youtu.be/KUzpFrReJNQ

Comment: Did you create your app with the Shell template? Do you have a `AppShell.xaml` file?

Comment: What you mean by `not working` ? Please provide more details about your problem .

Comment: not sure how to make a maui project with AppShell.xaml, is there any tutorial or anything?

Comment: Do you try to create a new blank project ? The default construction is using AppShell .

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, iam not really sure what i changed but i had to make a new project and in the AppShell.xaml there is the  tag and you have to add `Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"` and also add the `<ShellContent>` tag `<ShellContent>`